# Does different process has seperate copy of Shared Static variable or common copy?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, shared-memory

I am trying to understand the fundamental of shared memory concept. I trying to create a shared library having one function and one STATIC array variable. I want to access static array variable through the function of that shared library.

Here is my shared library

```
     //foo.c    
     #include <stdio.h>
     
    static int DATA[1024]={1 ,2 ,3 ,...., 1024};
    inline void foo(void)
    {
        int j, k=0;
        for(j=0;j<1024;j++)
        {
            k=DATA[j];
       }
        k+=0;    
    }
```

I have created shared library object (libfoo.so) by following instructions from [shared library](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html)

**Now my questions are**

1> If I access foo() from two different program ( program1 and program2), will there be separate copy of foo() function for program1 and program2 ?

2> will there be separate copy of **static DATA array** for program1 and program2 ?

3> Will they load into same physical memory location ?  If the static DATA array is loaded separately, is there any way to force/make it loaded into same memory location ?

4> Is there any way to find where the **static DATA array** is stored for program1 and program2 ?

I am using gcc under linux. Any help will be highly appreciated .Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "physical memory location"? Physical memory may or may not be accessible by a user program. A modern os provides your program with virtual memory, not physical.

Comment: @n.m. as shared memory concepts says that shared object is loaded into same physical memory. two program who are accessing the same shared library may have different virtual address space, but the physical address space is same.

Comment: @bholanath Shared libraries would only end up sharing the same physical memory for read-only stuff (e.g. the code), not something you can write to. It could possibly share your array if it was declared as `static const int DATA` - you can't find out if that's the case though.

Comment: Now this starts looking like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @nos you can, under linux — look at /proc/$pid/maps, there is a "shared" bit for each region.

Answer (score 6):

There is just one well defined way to share memory between processes: [Shared Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory). Accessing this memory from different processes requires proper synchronizing the access to that region (by the processes itself). Without synchronizing the access it would lead to a desaster on a multitasking OS like UNIX/Linux/Windows.

Answers in detail:

> If I access foo() from two different program ( program1 and program2), will there be separate copy of foo() function for program1 and program2 ?

No. When linking your program against a shared library, the code of function will being shared between multiple programs linked against that library.

> will there be separate copy of static DATA array for program1 and program2 ?

Yes. No data will being shared.

> Will they load into same physical memory location ? If the static DATA array is loaded separately, is there any way to force/make it loaded into same memory location ?

No (But read about Shared Memory above)

> Is there any way to find where the static DATA array is stored for program1 and program2 ?

Yes, you can find it out using GDB for example. But the programs can't find out about each other.

Comment: "separate copy of foo()" - no. why would be? it's shared.

Comment: foo() could be separate, it depends on whether the dynamic linker have to relocate (which includes making a copy of the code and patching memory references) the shared library at startup. (That probably won't happen if the shared library is compiled properly, with the `-fPIC` flag)

Comment: @nos Thanks for that information. I must admit that my knowledge about these things is, unfortunately, not based on too much practice in the last years.

Comment: @nos I am compiling with -fPIC option. While I declare static const int DATA , then I got address of DATA present in libfoo.so from both program same . I am using one tool to convert the virtual to physical address and then compare, both physical address are same.

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried to use gdb debugger to find address of DATA, but while I use break DATA[0] , I got this error message Function "DATA[0]" not defined. I use another ( not good approach) method to find the address of DATA[0] , print it inside foo() .

Comment: @bholanath The (virtual) address of data is simply `&data`. in gdb, `p &data` , or in C code, `printf("%p\n", (void*)&data);` (`&data` will have the same address as `&data[0]`)

Comment: @nos in gdb , I got this error - (gdb) p & DATA
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Comment: @nos I can use printf("%p\n", (void*)&data); in foo.c which is my shared library, but not from my program1 where I am indirectly access DATA via foo() function.

Answer (score 4):

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and wikipages on [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29), [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR)

Read also [Drepper's paper: *How to write shared libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Notice that application code running in some process don't care about *physical memory*, it only uses *virtual memory*. The [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) is free to move data in physical memory (e.g. swap out or swap in some pages). You should not care where (in physical RAM) is your data sitting (and that can change at any time, so from the point of view of application code, the question does not make any sense).

A shared object should be compiled as [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) using the `-fPIC` GCC flag (otherwise, it would contain too much [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29)). Then, the machine code of a function (like your `foo`) will usually sit in a shared read-only text segment - and the RAM containing it, if any, is shared between several processes.

Try the following command

```
cat /proc/self/maps
```

which shows you the virtual address space of the process running that `cat` command. Some of the memory segments are shared, others are a private copy...

Also read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) -to start a program and set its address space-, [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) -to create a new porocess-, [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) -to change the address space- (used by the dynamic linker [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html)), [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (to dynamically load a plugin), and [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) -to query the kernel about various things-. Notice that you might use [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) to lock memory into RAM (avoiding swapping it) if you have root privileges.

Each process has its own address space, in particular has its own data segments (for `static` or global `extern` variables, e.g. in shared objects or in the program executable). So of course if a process change some `static` data, the change is local to the process and is not visible to other processes running the same executable or the same shared library. To share data with some other process, use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_SHARED` (and probably `PROT_WRITE`) or Posix shared memory [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)...

<sup>BTW, this is a very common question. I'm quite sure I have answered nearly the same things on StackOverflow several times.</sup>

Comment: thanks for answering. Do you have any idea about whether both process store the static DATA array in their respective DATA SECTION and access from there ? or will they access same from .so files ?

Comment: Your question shows some confusion. Please follow all the links I gave you.

Comment: @ Basile, I agree with you that program doesn't care about physical address, it access data on the basis of virtual address. I am using one tool to find out the virtual address as well as physical address of currently valid process. What I want to make sure if I create a shared library having static data structure , will there be a single copy of that Or separate copy of that data structure in multiple process scenario?